# Android Kotlin save data class in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am working on an Android application in Kotlin which integrate Firebase.
Now I want to store my data (`Kotlin data class`) into Firebase Database.

Data Classes:

```
@Parcelize
data class Trip(
    val fromAddress: String,
    val toAddress: String,
    val fromLocation: String,
    val toLocation: String,
    val orderUid: String
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Order(val trip: Trip, val date: Date, var status: OrderStatus, val userUid: String) : Parcelable {
    var pickUpDate: Date? = null
    var dropOffDate: Date? = null
    var price: Double? = null

}
```

Fireabase Database write operation:

```
fun createNewOrder(
    fromAddress: String,
    toAddress: String,
    fromLocation: Location,
    toLocation: Location
) {
    val fromGeoLocation = fromLocation.convertToGeoLocation()
    val toGeoLocation = toLocation.convertToGeoLocation()
    val userUid = sharedPreferences[CURRENT_USER_UID_KEY, ""]!!
    val orderKey = databaseReference.child(DB_ORDERS_KEY).push().key
    val tripKey = databaseReference.child(DB_TRIPS_KEY).push().key
    val trip = orderKey?.let { createNewTrip(fromAddress, toAddress, it) }
    val order = trip?.let { Order(it, Date(), OrderStatus.PENDING, userUid) }

    if (trip != null && order != null && !userUid.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        ordersGeoFire.setLocation(trip.fromGeoLocation, fromGeoLocation)
        ordersGeoFire.setLocation(trip.toGeoLocation, toGeoLocation)
        val allData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
        allData["/$DB_TRIPS_KEY/$tripKey"] = trip?.convertToMap()
        allData["/$DB_ORDERS_KEY/$orderKey"] = order?.convertToMap()
        allData["/$DB_USERS_KEY/$userUid/$DB_ORDERS_KEY/$orderKey"] = true
        databaseReference.updateChildren(allData)
    }
}
```

I received this error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class kotlin.Unit

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the fileds inside your `Trip` class are not initialized. A recommended way in which you can create your model class would be:

```
class Trip(
        val displayName: String = "",
        val email: String = "",
        val photoUrl: String = "",
        val userId: String = ""
)
```

This is only what you need. And a way to create a new object of your `Trip` class, would be:

```
val trip = Trip(displayName, email, photoUrl, userId)
```

Comment: This is not the problem. I tried to create a record only for a Trip like the "tripKey?.let { databaseReference.child(DB_TRIPS_KEY).child(it).setValue(trip) }" (fields not initialized) and everything works fine. Maybe the problem is that I try to create a record of Order with inner Trip record. Will continue to investigate it

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, because I was forget to add `return type` in my extensions `convertToMap` functions. Now they look like this:

```
fun Trip.convertToMap(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    map["fromAddress"] = fromAddress
    map["toAddress"] = toAddress
    map["fromGeoLocation"] = fromGeoLocation
    map["toGeoLocation"] = toGeoLocation
    map["orderUid"] = orderUid
    return map
}
```

And also thanks to @Alex Mamo for his answer, it helps me in my investigation.

Now my code looks like this and works fine:

```
@Parcelize
data class Trip(
    var fromAddress: String = "",
    var toAddress: String = "",
    var fromGeoLocation: String = "",
    var toGeoLocation: String = "",
    var orderUid: String = ""
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Order(
    var trip: Trip? = null,
    var date: Date? = null,
    var status: OrderStatus? = null,
    var userUid: String = ""
) : Parcelable {
    var pickUpDate: Date? = null
    var dropOffDate: Date? = null
    var price: Double? = null
}

fun createNewOrder(
    fromAddress: String,
    toAddress: String,
    fromLocation: Location,
    toLocation: Location
): LiveData<Order> {
    orderLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    orderLiveData.value = null
    val userUid = sharedPreferences[CURRENT_USER_UID_KEY, ""]!!
    val orderKey = databaseReference.child(DB_ORDERS_KEY).push().key
    val tripKey = databaseReference.child(DB_TRIPS_KEY).push().key
    val trip = orderKey?.let { createNewTrip(fromAddress, toAddress, fromLocation, toLocation, it) }
    val order = trip?.let { Order(it, Date(), OrderStatus.PENDING, userUid) }

    if (trip != null && order != null && !userUid.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val allData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
        allData["/$DB_TRIPS_KEY/$tripKey"] = trip.convertToMap()
        allData["/$DB_ORDERS_KEY/$orderKey"] = order.convertToMap()
        allData["/$DB_USERS_KEY/$userUid/$DB_ORDERS_KEY/$orderKey"] = true
        databaseReference.updateChildren(allData) { databaseError, databaseReference ->
            if (databaseError == null) orderLiveData.value = order
        }
    }

    return orderLiveData
}
```

Hope this will be helpful